# do not submit form until function returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have this javascript code which has a function that calls other functions. The problem is the input.html form is getting submitted even if the fields are empty.. if I dont provide any input in the fields, the error messages are being shown but at the same time form gets submitted. there are numerous questions like this available but none is helping as they are not calling function within the function.. what can be the possible solution for this?

```js
function blankos() {
  var p = document.getElementById("windows");
  var q = document.getElementById("linux");

  if ((p.checked == false) && (q.checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("enteros").innerHTML = "Select an option";
    return false;
  } else if ((p.checked == true) || (q.checked == true)) {
    document.getElementById("enteros").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }

}

function blankfreq() {
  var r = document.getElementById("biannual");
  var s = document.getElementById("monthly");

  if ((r.checked == false) && (s.checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("enterfreq").innerHTML = "Select an option";
    return false;
  } else if ((r.checked == true) || (s.checked == true)) {
    document.getElementById("enterfreq").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }
}

function blankhour() {
  var i = document.getElementById("one");
  var ii = document.getElementById("two");
  var iii = document.getElementById("four");

  if ((i.checked == true) || (ii.checked == true) || (iii.checked == true)) {
    document.getElementById("enterhour").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}


function blank() {
  blankos();
  blankfreq();
  blankhour();
  checkselect();

}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return blank()" name="input" id="input" method="post" action="cgi-bin/review.cgi" >
```

Comment: try to return `false` from `blank` function if there is a validation error

Answer (score 1):

`blank()` doesn't return anything. Try:

```
function blank() {
    return blankos() && blankfreq() && blankhour() && checkselect();
}
```

This will only report the first error that's detected. If you want all of them to be reported, assign them to variables first.

```
function blank() {
  var ok1 = blankos();
  var ok2 = blankfreq();
  var ok3 = blankhour();
  var ok4 = checkselect();
  return ok1 && ok2 && ok3 && ok4;
}
```

I haven't looked at all the individual validation functions, though. You probably have bugs there that need to be fixed as well.

Comment: ...and fix bugs in the various functions it's calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` to restrict your form from submitting. Change your HTML from

```
<form onSubmit="return blank()" name="input" id="input" method="post" action="cgi-bin/review.cgi" >
```

to

```
<form name="input" id="input" method="post" action="cgi-bin/review.cgi" >
```

Then add this block of code

```
//id of the form is 'input'
$("#input").submit(function(e){
//if any of the inner functions return false then prevent from form submit
   if( !blankos() || !blankfreq() || !blankhour() || !checkselect()){
      e.preventDefault();
      return  false;
   }
});
```